# Django Rest - GET call returning malformed JSON

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a very simple installation of Django REST with a single table with 4 fields in it. 
I can interact with the API without any issues, but when I do a GET call the JSON I get back has these mystery 5 characters at the beginning that is breaking the JSON.

djangorestframework (2.3.14)
Python (2.7)

**models.py**

```
class SensorData(models.Model):
    string = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sensordata = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'sensor_data'
```

**serialzers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import SensorData


class SensorDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for test API endpoint
    """
    timestamp = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d')

    class Meta:
        model = SensorData
        fields = ('id', 'string', 'sensordata', 'timestamp')
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from serializers import SensorDataSerializer
from models import SensorData


class SensorDataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   """
   API endpoint for test sensor data
   """
    queryset = SensorData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SensorDataSerializer
```

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

    # Use hyperlinked styles by default.
    # Only used if the `serializer_class` attribute is not set on a view.
    'DEFAULT_MODEL_SERIALIZER_CLASS':
    'rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer',

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ],

    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    )

}
```

**My Response:**

```
)]}',
[{"id": 1, "string": "Jassen", "sensordata": "test", "timestamp": "2014-07-15"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the root cause which was Djangular, which has a middleware that was appending the bad characters to the beginning of the JSON.

```
'djangular.middleware.AngularJsonVulnerabilityMiddleware'
```

Hopefully that saves someone some time.